# Search by specific ID (regex) in cloudant DB (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, cloudant

I am building an Android app that internally stores data in a sqlite DB. We are using Cloudant library in our code.

I have different types of data in our DB  - all with different ID's. Ex: there can be data with GUID starting with A, B, C, D. Which means we can have GUID's like A_, B_ and so on.

Now, I want to fetch all DB entries whose GUID start with A_ and store them locally in the app itself for further processing. However, I only see a function to get all ID's from the DB. 
So, what I am doing is this:

```
List<String> allID = db.getIds();

for (int i=0;i<allID.size();i++)
{
      String guid = allID.get(i);
      if (guid.startsWith("A_"))
      {
         //store and process this guid.
      }
}
```

The variable db is an object of class DatabaseImpl.java from the cloudant library.

This definitely is good since we are only getting and processing the DB entries that we need. However, what I do not like about this approach is that we are actually getting all the GUID's in the DB and then checking each one of them.

I was hoping we would have a function which will allow us to search for ID's by a regex. Ex:
something like -

```
List<String> aID = db.getIds("A_");
```

More importantly, will this improve performance? I suspect internally in the DB also, we would need to still read all ID's and then get the ones we want. (Unless there is some optimization that helps speed this up)

Any inputs/comments.

Thanks in advance.
Andy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [query functionality](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/query.md).

For example, to get all the IDs starting `A_` You can use a selector like:

```
{"selector":{"$and":[{"_id": {"$gte": "A_"}},{"_id": {"$lt": "A_\uffff"}}]}}
```

In Cloudant's sync-android this is:

```java
Map<String, Object> idGt = Collections.singletonMap("_id", Collections.singletonMap("$gt", "A_"));
Map<String, Object> idLte = Collections.singletonMap("_id", Collections.singletonMap("$lte", "A_\uffff"));
Map<String, Object> query = Collections.singletonMap("$and", Arrays.asList(idGt, idLte));
QueryResult result = q.find(query);
for (DocumentRevision doc : result) {
    // do something with doc
}
```

Where `q` is a [`Query`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.cloudant/cloudant-sync-datastore-core/2.4.0/com/cloudant/sync/query/Query.html) object obtained from [`DocumentStore.query()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.cloudant/cloudant-sync-datastore-core/2.4.0/com/cloudant/sync/documentstore/DocumentStore.html#query--)

I'm not quite sure from your description, but additionally if you wanted only to replicate the subset of documents with the specific prefix to the device, you could use the string form of the JSON selector shown above as the argument to the [selector](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.cloudant/cloudant-sync-datastore-core/2.4.0/com/cloudant/sync/replication/ReplicatorBuilder.Pull.html#selector-java.lang.String-) method when building your pull replication.

Comment: Do you also know if this will help improve performance? I also have a guess that even if there is a way to get just id's that start with "A_", it would internally just search all documents one by one and retrieve the ones I want - somewhat similar to what I do. Of course, if internally they are doing some optimizations that improve this, it will be useful

Comment: It should be much faster [the _id field is automatically indexed](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/query.md#indexing-document-metadata-_id-and-_rev) so if you use the query functionality with the `_id` field name it won't be doing a table scan. It will retrieve the row keys from the sorted index of `_id`s; before pulling only the required documents from the table instead of reading all the documents. My impression from your example was that your GUID is stored as the document `_id` field, but you can create an index for any field in the JSON document if needed.